# Сравнение ключа словаря с элементом списка

Tags: python, python-2.7

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сравнить ключ словаря и элемент списка:

```
l = ["001000", "000001", "011001", "001100", "001001", "000000", "001011", "000000", "000011", "000001", "001101", "000000", "001110", "000001", "000000", "001011", "001111", "010001", "000001", "000010", "001100", "011110", "000000", "001111", "000101", "001111", "001100", "000111", "001001", "010011", "011110", "000000", "001110", "000110", "001101", "001110", "001111", "000100", "001111", "000000", "000100", "001111", "010001", "100000", "011000", "000110", "000100", "001111", "000000", "010010", "001111", "000111", "000001", "001100", "000110", "000110", "001101", "000000", "011000", "010011", "001111", "000000", "000011", "000001", "001101", "000000", "001110", "000110", "000000", "011011", "000011", "000001", "010011", "001001", "010011", "000000", "001110", "000001", "000000", "001111", "000010", "010001", "000001", "010011", "001110", "011101", "001010", "000000", "010000", "010100", "010011", "011110", "000000", "001101", "011101", "000000", "010000", "010001", "001001", "001011", "001001", "001110", "010100", "001100", "001001", "000000", "011000", "010011", "001111", "000000", "000101", "001111", "000000", "010000", "001111", "100001", "010010", "000001", "000000", "000001", "010010", "010011", "000110", "010001", "001111", "001001", "000101", "001111", "000011", "000000", "000011", "000001", "001101", "000000", "000101", "001111", "001100", "000111", "001110", "001111", "000000", "011011", "000011", "000001", "010011", "001001", "010011", "011110", "000000", "000001", "000000", "010000", "001111", "010011", "001111", "001101", "000000", "001100", "001111", "000111", "001001", "010011", "000110", "010010", "011110", "000000", "000011", "000000", "000101", "010001", "000110", "001010", "010101", "000000", "001001", "000000", "000011", "011101", "001000", "011101", "000011", "000001", "001010", "010011", "000110", "000000", "000001", "000011", "000001", "010001", "001001", "001010", "001110", "011101", "001010", "000000", "001011", "001111", "010001", "000001", "000010", "001100", "011110", "000000", "010010", "000000", "010011", "001001", "010011", "000001", "001110", "000001", "000000", "010010", "010000", "000001", "010010", "001001", "000010", "001111", "000000", "001000", "000001", "000000", "010010", "001111", "010011", "010001", "010100", "000101", "001110", "001001", "011000", "000110", "010010", "010011", "000011", "001111", "000000", "000001", "001100", "001100", "001111", "000000", "011111", "010011", "001111", "000000", "010001", "000001", "000101", "001001", "010010", "010011", "000000", "001011", "001111", "010001", "000001", "000010", "001100", "100001", "000000", "100001", "001110", "000000", "010011", "001111", "001100", "011110", "001011", "001111", "000000", "011000", "010011", "001111", "000000", "001111", "010011", "010010", "100000", "000101", "000001", "000000", "010100", "011001", "001100", "001001", "000000", "000100", "001001", "000100", "000001", "001110", "010011", "010010", "001011", "001001", "000110", "000000", "010010", "001100", "001001", "001000", "001110", "001001", "000000", "010010", "001111", "000000", "011010", "010100", "010000", "000001", "001100", "011110", "010111", "000001", "001101", "001001", "000000", "010000", "001111", "100001", "000011", "001001", "001100", "001001", "010010", "011110", "000000", "001110", "000001", "000000", "001011", "001111", "010001", "000001", "000010", "001100", "000110", "000000", "000101", "000110", "010010", "100001", "010011", "011110", "000000", "001101", "001001", "001110", "010100", "010011", "000000", "001110", "000001", "001000", "000001", "000101", "000000", "010000", "010001", "001001", "010010", "010011", "011101", "001011", "001111", "000011", "000001", "001100", "001001", "010010", "011110", "000000", "001011", "000000", "001110", "000001", "001101", "000000", "010000", "000001", "010001", "000001", "001100", "001001", "001000", "001111", "000011", "000001", "001100", "001001", "000000", "011001", "010011", "010100", "010001", "001101", "000001", "001110", "000001", "000000", "001011", "000001", "001011", "001111", "001010", "000000", "010011", "001111", "000000", "011001", "010011", "010100", "001011", "001111", "001010", "000000", "000011", "010001", "001111", "000101", "000110", "000000", "001111", "000100", "010001", "001111", "001101", "001110", "001111", "000100", "001111", "000000", "010000", "001111", "001110", "011000", "001001", "001011", "000001", "000000", "010010", "000000", "001100", "010100", "011000", "000001", "001101", "001001", "000000", "001111", "010010", "010011", "000001", "001100", "011110", "001110", "011101", "001101", "000000", "010000", "010001", "001001", "001011", "000001", "001000", "000001", "001100", "001001", "000000", "001110", "000110", "000000", "000101", "000011", "001001", "000100", "000001", "010011", "011110", "010010", "100001", "000000", "010000", "000110", "010001", "000110", "000100", "010001", "010100", "001000", "001001", "001100", "001001", "000000", "010000", "001111", "011000", "010011", "001001", "000000", "000011", "010010", "000110", "000000", "001011", "001111", "001110", "010011", "000110", "001010", "001110", "000110", "010001", "011101", "000000", "010010", "000000", "010011", "001111", "010000", "001100", "001001", "000011", "001111", "001101", "000000", "001110", "000001", "000000", "010010", "000011", "001111", "001010", "000000", "001011", "001111", "010001", "000001", "000010", "001100", "011110", "000000", "001111", "010010", "010011", "000001", "000011", "001001", "001100", "001001", "000000", "010000", "000001", "011000", "001011", "010100", "000000", "001011", "000001", "001000", "000001", "011011", "010010", "010011", "000001", "001110", "010010", "001011", "001001", "011011", "000000", "000101", "000110", "001110", "000110", "000100", "000000", "001001", "000000", "010100", "001100", "000110", "010011", "000110", "001100", "001001", "000000", "001011", "010011", "001111", "000000", "001001", "001101", "000000", "000101", "000001", "001100", "000000", "010000", "010001", "000001", "000011", "001111", "000000", "010011", "000001", "001011", "000000", "010010", "000110", "000010", "100001", "000000", "000011", "000110", "010010", "010011", "001001", "000000", "001001", "000000", "001111", "010011", "001011", "010100", "000101", "000001", "000000", "001111", "001110", "001001", "000000", "001000", "001110", "000001", "100000", "010011", "000000", "011000", "010011", "001111", "000000", "010100", "000000", "001110", "000001", "010010", "000000", "010010", "010011", "000001", "001110", "010111", "001001", "100001", "000000", "001110", "000001", "000000", "010011", "001001", "010011", "000001", "001110", "000110", "000000", "001110", "010100", "000111", "001110", "001111", "000000", "010011", "001111", "010000", "001100", "001001", "000011", "001111", "000000", "000101", "001111", "000010", "010001", "000001", "010011", "011110", "010010", "100001", "000000", "000101", "001111", "000000", "001100", "010100", "001110", "001110", "001111", "001010", "000000", "010010", "010011", "000001", "001110", "010111", "001001", "001001", "000000", "001110", "001111", "001101", "000110", "010001", "000000", "000011", "001111", "010010", "000110", "001101", "011110", "000000", "001011", "000001", "001011", "000000", "010011", "000001", "001101", "000000", "010010", "011101", "000100", "010001", "000001", "001100", "000000", "010001", "000110", "000001", "001100", "000000", "010000", "010001", "001111", "010011", "001001", "000011", "000000", "010000", "010010", "000111"]   
b = []
i = 0
k = {0: " ",1: "a",2: "b",3: "v",4: "g",5: "d",6: "e",7: "zh",8: "z",9: "i",10: "y",11: "k",12: "l",13: "m",14: "n",15: "o",16: "p",17: "r",18: "s",19: "t",20: "u",21: "f",22: "h",23: "c",24: "ch",25: "sh",26: "sh'",27: "y",28: "i",29: "y",30: "e",31: "yu",32: "ya"} 
translated  = [] 


while i < len(l): 
 b.append(int(l[i],2)) 
 i += 1 

print("Encrypted message: " + str(b))  
print("") 
print("") 
print("Lenght of the message: " + str(len(b))) 

m = 0 
j = 0 

while j < len(b): 
 while m < len(k):          
  if b[j] == k[m]:  
   translated.append(k[m])
   j += 1 
  m += 1 

 print("")   
 print(translated)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dct = {
    'hello' : 'world',
    1 : 2
}
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 'hello']
foo = lambda array, dict: [('Элемент {0} совпал с key {1}').format(x, y) for x in array for y in dict if x == y]
```

**Результат:**

```
['Элемент 1 совпал с key 1', 'Элемент hello совпал с key hello']
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! ;)

Comment: @Михаил это совершенно неправильное использование словарей. Вместо: `for x in array_ for y in dict_ if x == y` достаточно `for x in array_ if x in dict_` в большинстве случаев.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы узнать является ли элемент списка ключом в словаре, можно использовать `in` оператор: **`element in some_dict`**.

В вашем случае, чтобы декодировать `b` список, используя `k` словарь:

```
translated = [k[n] for n in b]
# -> list(map(k.__getitem__, b))
```

---

В целом код можно упростить. К примеру, вместо:

```
#XXX НЕ ДЕЛАЙТЕ ТАК!
while i < len(l): 
 b.append(int(l[i],2)) 
 i += 1
```

можно писать просто:

```
b = [int(bits, 2) for bits in l]
```

В вашем случае словарь не нужен, можно просто список использовать:

```
k = [" ", "a", "b", "v", "g", "d", "e", "zh", "z", "i", "y", "k", "l",
     "m", "n", "o", "p", "r", "s", "t", "u", "f", "h", "c", "ch",
     "sh", "sh'", "y", "i", "y", "e", "yu", "ya"]
```

Код: `translated = [k[n] for n in b]` создаёт тот же список, что и в случае со словарём.

Общее замечание: используйте более говорящие имена, чтобы легче было код читать.

Answer (score 0):

```
translated = []
for a in l:
    try:
        translated.append(k[int(a, 2)])
    except KeyError:
        print('not found %s' % a)
        break
    else:
        print(translated)
```